# How do I change the label of an exFAT partition without formatting?

Tags: partition

I have a flash drive that is formatted as exFAT. I wish to change the label of the drive without formatting.

I've seen ways of doing this for ext4, fat or ntfs partitions but not for exFAT. Is this possible? how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the tools you are using (or that are available for your distributions) you'll need to use either [exfatlabel](https://www.mankier.com/8/exfatlabel)

```
exfatlabel <device> <label>
```

from [exfat-utils](https://github.com/relan/exfat) which is provided by the older FUSE implementation of exFAT or [tune.exfat](https://www.mankier.com/8/tune.exfat)

```
tune.exfat -L <label> <device>
```

from [exfatprogs](https://github.com/exfatprogs/exfatprogs) which is the userspace counterpart of the 5.7 kernel implementation and should be available in newer distributions.

Comment: Not sure if this was a new addition since the original date from this response, but now exfatprogs also provides an  `exfatlabel` utility, so you can use the first one anyway.

Comment: `sudo exfatlabel /dev/sdb1 ExtremePro` did the trick for me (original label was "Extreme Pro"), with exfatprogs 1.2.2-1 (on linux 6.6.10-1-lts).

Answer (score 1):

Did not try it out, but [exfatlabel](https://man.archlinux.org/man/community/exfat-utils/exfatlabel.8.en) should do what you need.